# Agregar una excepción en replaceAll de javascript

Tags: javascript, replaceall

tengo un texto al que le estoy añadiendo el ID del widget de un CSS automáticamente en cada punto, el problema es que tengo un valor que contiente un punto, por ejemplo

```
width: 8.5%;
```

y quiero obviamente añadir números como excepción para que no se añada el ID del widget, o en todo caso y si es que fuera posible que ningún valor del CSS se vea afectado, es decir nada dentro de las llaves `{ }`

ejemplo del valor afectado:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var widgetId = "service"
  var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
  var res = str.replaceAll(".", `#${widgetId}.`);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
    <p id="demo">
        <code>
        .spacer-line {
        border-bottom-width: 20px;
        width: 8.5%;
        border-color: black;
    }
    .card-title {
        color: blue !important;
    }
    .card-body {
       text-align: left;
       padding: 80px 20px 60px 90px;
    }
  </code>
 </p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Reemplazar</button>
```

estoy haciendo un `value = value.replaceAll('.', '#' + widgetId + ' .');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo más recomendable sería hacerlo con una expresión regular como `/^(\s)*(\.)/gm`

- `^` - Comenzar a buscar desde el inicio de cada línea
- `(\s)*` - Cero o más caracteres de espacio, incluyendo saltos de línea
- `(\.)` - Buscar un punto, debe escaparse, porque de lo contrario es cualquier caracter excepto salto de línea
- `gm` - Son directivas, donde la `g` especifica que se busque globalmente (en toda la cadena) con lo que se puede usar `.replace()` en vez de `.replaceAll()`; la directiva `m` especifica que se trata de un texto multilínea

**Nota:** Cambié el ID del párrafo a la etiqueta `<code>` y agregué una etiqueta `<pre>` para mantener el formato.

```js
let str = document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML;

function myFunction() {
    let widgetId = "service"
    // Comentado para trabajar solo sobre la cadena original
    // let str = document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML;
    let res = str.replace(/^(\s)*(\.)/gm, `#${widgetId} .`);
    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = res;
}

function reset() {
    document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML = str;
}
```

```html
<p>
<pre><code id="demo">     .spacer-line { /* Lo moví al inicio de la cadena */
        border-bottom-width: 20px;
        width: 8.5%;
        border-color: black;
    }
.card-title { /* Lo moví al incio de la línea */
        color: blue !important;
    }
    .card-title .card-body {
       text-align: left;
       padding: 80px 20px 60px 90px;
    }
    div.este-no-cambia { /* No hay espacio antes del punto, no se remplaza */
        width: 25.5%;
    }
</code></pre>
</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Reemplazar</button>
    <button onclick="reset()">Restablecer</button>
```

Si quieres saber más acerca de expresiones regulares, realiza tus pruebas en: https://regexr.com/

Comment: gracias amigo, ahora tengo una pregunta, cómo podría hacer que el widgetId sea solamente añadido en cada salto de linea? me explico porque si hay un     .card-body .card-text se añade 2 veces la etiqueta, cosa que no se quiere

Comment: he intentando con (/^(\.)|(\n\.)/gm, ` #${widgetId} .`) pero no me funciona así

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma, tu intento iba bien, solo faltaba `\s+` después del salto de línea. Actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: gracias! una última duda, yo molestando lo siento jaja. dices que \s+ busca uno o más espacios, sin embargo si a la primera línea de tu ejemplo pongo varios espacios no añade el widgetID, qué puede ser?

Comment: @AndréCuellarAvaroma, al final quedó con una sola expresión regular, aprovechando que `\s` representa espacios y saltos de línea.

Comment: muchas gracias! ya voy practicando también con la herramienta que pusiste :)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar utilizando string literals en vez de contatenar con "+" por ejemplo:

```
str.replaceAll(".", `#${widgetId}.`);
```

Con eso literalmente no importa lo que tengas dentro de las `` te va a respetar el orden y los espacios

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero acabo de probar así y sigue ocurriendo, actualicé mi pregunta con tu respuesta y como podrás ver, los valores dentro de las llaves {} siguen siendo afectados, como el número de ejemplo